# What's differences between PV and manual mount?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mount, nfs

I have an external NFS service, and there are two ways to mount.
Using PV

```
      volumes:
      - name: nfs-volume-0
        nfs:
          path: /data/mypath
          server: 10.123.3.124
```

Using mount in container

```
mount -t nfs 10.123.3.124:/data/mypath /data/mypath
```

What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 0):

Using `volumes:` is usually possible, running **mount**(8) in a container usually isn't.  A container is usually prohibited from mounting additional filesystems (even if it's running as root, via Linux capabilities) and unless you're able to circumvent this that **mount**(8) call just won't work.  This will be true in both Kubernetes and plain Docker.

Stepping up one more level, an NFS PersistentVolumeClaim can be a couple of layers isolated from your application.  If you were able to call **mount**(8) inside the container, it would have to know the address of the NFS server and the path, and that could make it hard to run in other environments (pre-production, QA, and developer environments presumably have different setups).  The PVC approach lets the application assume something is mounted on `/data/mypath`, and the deployment configuration specifies what's actually there.  This would also let you straightforwardly change that setting to something other than NFS (maybe in a development environment you can use local files; maybe you decide a local volume is faster and more reliable).